# Colour Theme Switcher Not Working Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following file `theme.js`

I have 3 modes `dark`, `classic` and `light`. And I toggle the modes using the Buttons as mentioned in `Home.js` file

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { createContext, useMemo, useState } from "react";

export const tokens = (mode) => ({
  ...(mode === "dark"
    ? {
        // DARK MODE
        primary1: {
          500: "#1E2230",
        },

        primary2: {
          500: "#171A25",
        },

        primary3: {
          500: "#242937",
        },
        button: {
          main: "#3555FF",
        },
      }
    : mode === "classic"
    ? {
        // CLASSIC MODE
        primary1: {
          500: "#211839",
        },
        primary2: {
          500: "#150D29",
        },
        primary3: {
          500: "#211839",
        },
      }
    : // LIGHT MODE
      {
        primary1: {
          100: "#040507",
          200: "#090a0e",
          300: "#0d0e15",
          400: "#12131c",
          500: "#161823",
          600: "#45464f",
          700: "#73747b",
          800: "#a2a3a7",
          900: "#d0d1d3",
        },

        primary2: {
          100: "#06070a",
          200: "#0c0e13",
          300: "#12141d",
          400: "#181b26",
          500: "#1e2230",
          600: "#4b4e59",
          700: "#787a83",
          800: "#a5a7ac",
          900: "#d2d3d6",
        },

        primary3: {
          100: "#07080b",
          200: "#0e1016",
          300: "#161921",
          400: "#1d212c",
          500: "#242937",
          600: "#50545f",
          700: "#7c7f87",
          800: "#a7a9af",
          900: "#d3d4d7",
        },
      }),
});

const DARK_MODE_BACKGROUND = "#131017";
// const CLASSIC_MODE_BACKGROUND = "#16121C";
const CLASSIC_MODE_BACKGROUND = "red";
const LIGHT_MODE_BACKGROUND = "white";

export const themeSettings = (mode) => {
  const colors = tokens(mode);
  return {
    palette: {
      mode: mode,
      ...(mode === "dark"
        ? {
            primary: {
              main: colors.primary1[500],
            },
            secondary: {
              main: colors.primary2[500],
            },
            background: {
              default: DARK_MODE_BACKGROUND,
            },
          }
        : mode === "classic"
        ? {
            primary: {
              main: colors.primary1[500],
            },
            secondary: {
              main: colors.primary2[500],
            },
            background: {
              default: CLASSIC_MODE_BACKGROUND,
            },
          }
        : {
            primary: {
              main: colors.primary1[100],
            },
            secondary: {
              main: colors.primary2[100],
            },
            background: {
              default: LIGHT_MODE_BACKGROUND,
            },
          }),
    },
  };
};

// context for color mode
export const ColorModeContext = createContext({
  toggleColorMode: () => {},
});

export const useMode = () => {
  // set the mode
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("dark");
  const colorMode = useMemo(
    () => ({
      toggleColorMode: (mode) => {
        switch (mode) {
          case "dark":
            setMode("dark");
            break;
          case "classic":
            setMode("classic");
            break;
          case "light":
          default:
            setMode("light");
            break;
        }
      },
    }),
    []
  );

  const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(themeSettings(mode)), [mode]);
  return [theme, colorMode, setMode];
};
```

My Issue is that when I click on Dark Button then it toggles to Dark Mode, when I click on Light then it toggles to Light Mode but When I click on Classic Button then the app breaks I don't understand what am I doing wrong

```
import { Button, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { ColorModeContext, tokens } from "../Theme";
import { useTheme } from "@emotion/react";

export default function Home() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
  const colorMode = useContext(ColorModeContext);

  return (
    <div>
      hi
      <Button
        onClick={() => colorMode.toggleColorMode("dark")}
        variant="contained"
      >
        Dark
      </Button>
      <Button
        onClick={() => colorMode.toggleColorMode("classic")}
        variant="contained"
      >
        Classic
      </Button>
      <Button
        onClick={() => colorMode.toggleColorMode("light")}
        variant="contained"
      >
        Light
      </Button>
      <Typography variant="h1" color="primary"></Typography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Where am I going wrong can anyone guide through ?

The error I get in the console is

> MUI: The palette mode `classic` is not supported.
>
> ERROR Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'primary')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'primary')
> at body (http://localhost:8080/main.js:3923:45)
> at styles (http://localhost:8080/main.js:3952:8)
> at styles (http://localhost:8080/main.js:3981:24)
> at GlobalStyles.globalStyles (http://localhost:8080/main.js:5598:69)
> at handleInterpolation (http://localhost:8080/main.js:1619:24)
> at serializeStyles (http://localhost:8080/main.js:1733:15)
> at http://localhost:8080/main.js:1229:87
> at http://localhost:8080/main.js:826:12
> at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:8080/main.js:32413:18)
> at updateForwardRef (http://localhost:8080/main.js:35329:20)

Comment: @Liam I did not understand what have I written wrong ?

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

MUI internally only has support for two modes 'light' and 'dark'.

> Material UI comes with two palette modes: light (the default) and dark. [1]

The error rightly suggests that behavior. "MUI: The palette mode classic is not supported."

Since you are managing the `mode` externally by yourself on your `ColorModeContext` component. You could remove the `mode` from the `palette` object itself. Your color generation should work normally, and referencing mode should now be done from `useMode` hook instead of `useTheme`.

```js
export const themeSettings = (mode) => {
  const colors = tokens(mode);
  return {
    palette: {
      mode: mode, //  remove this
      ...(mode === "dark"
        ? {
            primary: {
              main: colors.primary1[500],
            },
            secondary: {
              main: colors.primary2[500],
            },
            background: {
              default: DARK_MODE_BACKGROUND,
            },
          }
        : mode === "classic"
        ? {
            primary: {
              main: colors.primary1[500],
            },
            secondary: {
              main: colors.primary2[500],
            },
            background: {
              default: CLASSIC_MODE_BACKGROUND,
            },
          }
        : {
            primary: {
              main: colors.primary1[100],
            },
            secondary: {
              main: colors.primary2[100],
            },
            background: {
              default: LIGHT_MODE_BACKGROUND,
            },
          }),
    },
  };
};
```

After removing that, your way of getting colors should now be done with the `useMode` hooks instead of `useTheme` you are using.

On you `useMode()` hook you could also pass the current mode state.

```js
export const useMode = () => {
  ..
  ..
  return { theme, colorMode, setMode, mode }; //  changed to object for easy destructuring
}
```

```js
export default function Home() {
  const { theme, colorMode, mode } = useMode();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);

  return (
    <div>
      hi
      <Button
        onClick={() => colorMode.toggleColorMode("dark")}
        variant="contained"
      >
        Dark
      </Button>
      <Button
        onClick={() => colorMode.toggleColorMode("classic")}
        variant="contained"
      >
        Classic
      </Button>
      <Button
        onClick={() => colorMode.toggleColorMode("light")}
        variant="contained"
      >
        Light
      </Button>
      <Typography variant="h1" color="primary"></Typography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Further note, I think you should

1. Move the state for `useMode` to `ColorModeContext.Provider`'s `value`.
2. Wrap your `ColorModeContext.Provider` above `ThemeProvider`
3. `useMode` should now just call `useContext(ColorModeContext)`
4. Pass the `theme` you receive from `useMode` hook to the `ThemeProvider` MUI provides.

The logic is fine, its the steps that are all over the place.

References:

1. https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/

Comment: If I remove that then how will I receive the selected mode with the color palette ? I need the selected mode that the user selects from 3 buttons or maybe a dropdown and based on that I get the entire palette light, dark, classic

Comment: You are getting the mode but you are not passing it to the palette object.

Comment: I see your issue. You are generating the colors based on `theme.palette.mode`. As I said earlier that referencing mode should now be done from `ColorModeContext`. So inside your context, create a state of mode which is accessible to all your app/pages. And get mode from there instead of theme. Because theme only supports explicit mode of `light/dark`. Create a minimal reproducible context on codesandbox for more context

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue in past and solution that work for me is to change import from **@mui/material** to **@mui/material/styles**. so what you have to do is just change you import from import { createTheme } from @mui/material to import { createTheme } from @mui/material/styles. Reason behind this is by using @mui/material/style it can handle all the issues internally.

change from

> import { createTheme } from @mui/material;

to

> import { createTheme } from @mui/material/styles.